# How to get the behavior change notification to email address?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'd like to get the behavior change notification, but I have no idea to do so.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Behavior-Change-Policy
This page says, snowflake sends email notification of behavior changes to a mailing list of users who are authorized to submit support cases.

In order to get the autlirized to submit support cases, I did this way:https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

I expect I can check the pending behavior change like this page:
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Use-the-Notification-Center, but the checkbox doesn't apper.

How can I get the notificaiton? and, what point in my process is wrong?

Comment: Are you an authorized user with Snowflake Support?

Answer (score 0):

You must be a Community Enabled Customer e.g. you can submit a support ticket via the community page.

Alternatively, you must have Organization enabled and be the Orgadmin of your company, then you can opt-in to receive the notification described here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-admin.html

The Notification Contacts page of Snowsight lets you set email addresses to receive security, privacy, and product notifications.

Emails are sent in accordance with the Snowflake Policy Notice.

**Note**

Only users with the ORGADMIN role can view contact information. Other users will not see Admin » Contacts. The role need not be currently active but only granted.